# Сортировка по атрибуту объекта массива объектов в jsonb

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица полем `jsonb` с записями вида

```
  uid | jsonb
-------------------------------
  1   | [{"id": 3}]
  2   | [{"id": 4}, {"id": 5}]
```

Есть ли возможность создать индекс, который будет использован планировщиком при выполнении запроса, получающего выборку отсортированную по значению атрибута id из объекта, который хранится в поле jsonb?

```
  uid | qq
-------------------------------
   2  | {"id": 5}
   2  | {"id": 4}
   1  | {"id": 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

[USING GIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) требуемый метод

1. Populate:

````
t=# create table so68 (i int,j jsonb,t text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 12.654 ms
t=# do $$ begin for _r in 1..99999 loop insert into so68 select _r,concat('[{"id": ',_r,'}, {"id": ',_r+_r,'}]')::jsonb,'rogfj weghiuhg eihg iehg ih gipueh gpiuewh gpiuew gpiewhg piewhg piuewg ew'; end loop; end; $$;   DO
Time: 698.833 ms
t=# select * from so68 limit 4;```

>      i |           j            |                                     t
>     ---+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>      1 | [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}] | rogfj weghiuhg eihg iehg ih gipueh gpiuewh gpiuew gpiewhg piewhg piuewg ew
>      2 | [{"id": 2}, {"id": 4}] | rogfj weghiuhg eihg iehg ih gipueh gpiuewh gpiuew gpiewhg piewhg piuewg ew
>      3 | [{"id": 3}, {"id": 6}] | rogfj weghiuhg eihg iehg ih gipueh gpiuewh gpiuew gpiewhg piewhg piuewg ew
>      4 | [{"id": 4}, {"id": 8}] | rogfj weghiuhg eihg iehg ih gipueh gpiuewh gpiuew gpiewhg piewhg piuewg ew
>     (4 rows)
````

2. Index:

```
t=# create index so69 on so68 using GIN (j);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 586.440 ms
t=# explain analyze select * from so68 where j @> '{"id":8}';
```

3. Plan:

```
>      Bitmap Heap Scan on so68  (cost=7.28..106.53 rows=100 width=145) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=0 loops=1)
>        Recheck Cond: (j @> '{"id": 8}'::jsonb)
>        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2
>        Heap Blocks: exact=1
>        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on so69  (cost=0.00..7.25 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=2 loops=1)
>              Index Cond: (j @> '{"id": 8}'::jsonb)
>      Planning time: 0.108 ms
>      Execution time: 0.089 ms
>     (8 rows)

    
    Time: 0.560 ms
```

4. Теперь насильно предлагаем sequential scan:

```
t=# set enable_bitmapscan to off;
SET
Time: 0.149 ms
t=# explain analyze select * from so68 where j @> '{"id":8}';
```

> ```
>                                                   QUERY PLAN
>     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>      Seq Scan on so68  (cost=0.00..3462.99 rows=100 width=145) (actual time=15.369..15.369 rows=0 loops=1)
>        Filter: (j @> '{"id": 8}'::jsonb)
>        Rows Removed by Filter: 99999
>      Planning time: 0.055 ms
>      Execution time: 15.387 ms
>     (5 rows)
>
>    Time: 15.738 ms
> ```

**вывод**: GIN индекс используется и не зря

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Думаю, gin-индекс будет не эффективен для решения моей задачи - разложить записи и отсортировать по атрибуту id из элементов массива хранимого в jsonb.